# WebApi request through Sahi is giving error. What could be the cause?

Tags: javascript, rest, sahi

Here is JSON that we can see in fiddler when developer is running his code

```
{
    "EventId": 0,
    "Title": "Matz test event",
    "Topics": "203,207",
    "Type": {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Conference"
    },
    "Notes": "Test Meeting Notes",
    "StartDate": "03 March 2014, 05:00 PM",
    "EndDate": "03 March 2014, 06:00 PM",
    "Venue": "Venue 1",
    "Address": "ub Plaza , st Marks Road, bangalore ,India",
    "Address1": "Ub Plaza",
    "Address2": "St Marks Road",
    "City": "Bangalore",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "India",
    "Latitude": "12.9716396",
    "Longitude": "77.6010666",
    "Contactids": "0~0",
    "OcmContactIds": "61756~52122",
    "LastNames": "Andrews~Andrews",
    "FirstNames": "Alyse~Benjamin",
    "MiddleNames": "G.~",
    "FirmIds": "MRGNSTOO4~WNGRSS001",
    "FirmNames": "Morgan Stanley & Co. LLC~Columbia Wanger Asset Management,LLC",
    "RsvpIds": "3~2",
    "AttendanceIds": "1~0",
    "ContactNotes": "~",
    "TopicIds": "203~207",
    "CoprPartIds": "87~47",
    "CorpBrokerId": 8
}
```

In this we have `"Type":{"Id":7,"Name":"Conference"}`, a name and id pair. We wrote the below code to send the request.

```
$request.setBody("{\"Title\":\"Matz test event Updated\",\"Type\":[{\"Id\":7,\"Name\":\"Conference\"}],\"StartDate\":\"03 March 2014, 06:00 PM\",\"EndDate\":\"03 March 2014, 07:00 PM\"}");
```

However, I am getting "Select a valid Type" error.

Any idea why is this happening like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the JSON, you can use stringify() and pass the string to $request.setBody.